# Incorrect bit depth showing in output Tiff file generated using Ghostscript

Tags: ghostscript.net

I am using compression  **LZW** and bit depth **1,8,12 & 24**, but in the output file generated i am always getting bit depth 1.
If i am using bit depth 12 i should get 12 in output.

I am using compression mode **-sDEVICE=tifflzw.**

I also tried **-sDEVICE=tiff12nc** for 12bit,**-sDEVICE=tiff24nc** for 24bit,**-sDEVICE=tiffgray** for 8 bit and finally **-sCompression=lzw** as compression mode.

Now if i try for 8bit it is working, in output file i am getting 8 bit.
but if i use 12 bit , in output file it is 24 bit.

**Ghostscript.NET version 1.1.8.0**

Comment: This is probably going to seem like a dumb question, but are you certain the output is 1-bit ? Its all coming out monochrome ? When I try tiff12nc here, and then use tiffdump it says the BitsPerSample (ie bit depth) is <4 4 4> so 4 bits per sample, 3 components = 12 bits. The other obvious question is what version of Ghostscript, on what Operating System, and sourced from where ? Can you post an example (full) command line and a specimen input file and the result you see somewhere (eg DropBox) so we can look at it?

Comment: Ghostscript..NET version 1.1.8.0, yes output is 1bit

Comment: OK Ghostscript.NET is not Ghostscript (though it does use Ghostscript), so you've got the wrong tag. I've corrected that for you. I suspect the maintainer of Ghostscript.NET will want to see the code you are using to create 12-bit output. I can't help you with Ghostscript.NET, you could try the same thing with regular Ghostscript from the command shell and see what happens.